# Can the numbers $8, 15, 24$ be terms of an arithmetic progression with the common difference anything other than 1?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

Let the common ratio/difference of the arithmetic progression be a number d. The exercise forces $d=/=1$ (d cannot be one).
Is there any sort of proof for this exercise or am I supposed to play a guessing game?
For example:

We say $15=8+k*d$, where $k$ is a natural number and $d$ is the common difference which is a real number.
We also know $15 = 8+7$ therefore $k*d = 7$. We can maybe consider $k = 14$ and $d = 1/2$. We know $24 = 15+9 = 15 + x*d$.
$x$ is also a natural number and $d=1/2$ from our guess a few rows above. $x*d=9 => x = 9/d => x = 18$.
Therefore there is a $14$ term difference between $8$ and $15$ (including $15$) and a $18$ term difference between $15$ and $24$ (including $24$) and the common difference can be $1/2$.

The answer to the exercise question, in this case, would be *yes*. But this takes a bit of work (sometimes you may not get the correct guess from the start) if I may say so and maybe there is a more thorough proof.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is requiring the common difference to be a whole number. Or else you are right that taking $d = 1/2$ would work. You could also take $d = 1/n$ for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: If the common difference is an integer $d$, then $d$ divides $15-8=7$ and $24-15=9$

Comment: It applies to all real numbers, see this: [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327983/does-the-formula-of-an-arithmetic-series-apply-to-all-real-numbers), even if you use Rationals for d, then you still have infinite solutions